# Android Studio Firebase Can Only Upload 1 Image

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

When I create a StorageReference and try to save drawings in there, I can only save 1 single drawing and it won't get into the right folder. If you look at the images, you see the only image created. Always when I run the app and upload the drawing, the onfailure is called and the message says that it's an unknows error.

```
public void uploadDrawing(Uri uri) {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "uID: " + uID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String nameOfDrawing = null;

    nameOfDrawing = "drawing " + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

    StorageReference filepath = drawingsRef.child("drawings").child(nameOfDrawing);

    filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Målningen sparades korrekt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Något fel inträffades tyvärr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.i("AppInfo", e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you want to upload multiple images at once ?

Comment: Thx can you send a link to the specific question plz.

Comment: this guy has explain in his tutorial video very nicely [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXR8-9amqGo)